# pip: no matching distribution found for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

[image]
Although I tried hard, I couldn't solve the problem. I can not give any other details because I do not know the reason. If you are curious about a detail, ask, let me answer it immediately.

Comment: What version of Python? What version of pip? The most likely cause is you are attempting to search for tensorflow on a python distribution where it's no longer available.

Comment: @gallen python 3.8.5, pip 20.1.1

Comment: also do `pip -V`. You might think you're using the `pip` attached to your 3.8 Python installation, but it's actually 2.6 or something older than sin :)

Comment: @Anonim Can you run `curl https://pypi.org` to see if their servers are available to you? Given that none of the solutions have worked so far, [there's a chance you may be blacklisted](https://bhch.github.io/posts/2017/04/fix-the-pip-error-couldnt-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement/#solution)

Comment: SOLVED THE PROBLEM WITH YOU. I practiced what he said both things. First, I uninstalled the latest version and installed version 3.7. Secondly, I had 32-bit installed. Tensorflow designed for 64 bit. So I installed the 64-bit one and the problem is solved. Thank you all for your help 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow) only works on 64-bit systems, so you might want to upgrade your computer.

If that's not the problem, try doing

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: I am using the latest version.

Comment: Are you using a 32 bit computer?

Comment: you can run `wmic os get osarchitecture` in cmd to see if you're on 32 or 64 bit

Comment: 64 bit Computer @Denis

Answer (score 1):

If you have an older version of Python installed (v2), usually *pip* will refer to Python 2.x*.

Try

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install an older version of TensorFlow, you may be using a version of Python that's too new.  I had this issue trying to install `tensorflow-gpu==1.15` using Python 3.8.

You can check by looking at the files listed on PyPI, e.g.: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/1.15.5/#files

Then, try switching to a Python version that has an available [wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `python>=3.8`TensorFlow v1 is unlikely to work. You need to o install `python<=3.7`. You can create a virtual environment with conda. 
`conda create -n envname python=3.7 -y`. 
In case you have already created a virtual environment with conda you can do 
`conda activate envname`
`conda install python=3.7`